# See size and the content of file (the new added strings) while writing to it in java after each refresh

Tags: java, printwriter, bufferedwriter, writer

I have used `PrintWriter` to write to a text file with java, the process takes time, bcz there is an iteration process, at end of each iteration, a string is appended to the file, if I wait till the process ends, I can open and see the content of the file without problem, but how to see the updating process to the file while it is still writing to, e.g. I refresh inside the folder then I see the size becomes larger and larger with each refresh click?

Comment: `flush()` regularly.

Comment: Do you mean after  pw.append("Sthg); should I use pw.flush()?    pw is Print Writer

Comment: Call `pw.flush()` after `n` iterations after your loop. Choose `n` (the "batch size") based on the trade-off that flushing buffers to disk takes time (which is why you don't typically see the file size increasing on refresh, the output is **buffered**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see the progress of your stuff being written into the file, since it might not actually be.

First: Java Streams usually optimize access to the harddrive, to access it as little as possible since doing so is slow. To force Java to do what it thinks is wrinting to disk, call `PrintWriter.flush()` after you have appended something.

Second: even that might not do the trick, since most operating systems do the same optimisation with the same result, and you can't simply force you os to `flush()`.

As already mentioned, the best you can do is `Printwriter.flush()`.

Comment: Of course there are performance concerns using `flush()`; there's a reason it works like this. The OP will need to decide whether this functionality is really important enough to negatively impact the actual write process.

Comment: Poohl, thank you it worked, thanks also to the others :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Elliott mentioned you should do pw.flush() after each append to see the size change immediately.